# Magento 2 : Add custom script just after body tag

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, script

I am using Magento 2.3

Can anyone please provide appropriate way for

How can i add my custom script code after the  tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your xml add below code,

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
    <block name="custom">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

In case above code not works, you can do it by adding a phtml and declaring script in that phtml.

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block template="Namespace_Modulename::custom.phtml" name="meaningful_name"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

In custom phtml, declare your script,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">Your script</script>
```

Comment: This is a correct and proper answer

Comment: Which one did u use @Sam?

Comment: @aravind, did you mean default.xml or any other layout xml file by "In your xml add below code". I need to have a script tag right after the body tag for all the pages in the site. Please advice.

Comment: @CodeForGood You need to add the code in default.xml to display in all the pages

Comment: @aravind, thanks. I just found it out. I shall do it and I hope that this works otherwise I need to try the second solution you offered.

Comment: @aravind, Could you please tell me if there is a need to create a new module to employ your first solution? I have some modules under app/code that have default.xml.

Comment: You could add default.xml in app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. **Create a custom file *custom_body.phtml* to add your script code right after body tag.**

custom_body.phtml

`/app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custom_body.phtml`

Write you script code  :

`<script type="text/javascript">Your script</script>`

Step 2.
default .xml file: `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` 
add this:

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
 <block name="custom.body" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom_body.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but what worked for me was adding class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" to aravind's answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/201204)